# Jackson json to java map + cut json inner objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `Json` like:

```
{
    "A": {
        "a": "1",
        "b": 1001,
        "c": 1234567891011121314,
        "d": 10082,
        "e": 10584,
        "f": 11013
    },
    "exclude1": "10052824",
    "exclude2": "588265"
}
```

I want to map it to Java HashMap but without exclude1 and exclude2 fields.
It will be something like: `Map key a -> value 1, Map key b - value 23`
Is there any standard annotations to do this?

Comment: Annotations like `@JsonIgnore` are not applicable. Looking at the deserialization options (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) it also seems like there's no option for you. Why not do `map.remove("exclude")`?

Comment: Where is" value 23" supposed to come from?

Comment: this is value in hashmap. Key is "b" and value is "23"